# Decoding Complicated JSON Array vb.net

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, serialization, decode

I've been having a lot of troubles with a problem for a few days now and I'm getting very frustrated about it!
I would like to know how to decode a JSON Array in VB.NET 4.5 Framework. I'm trying to use the deserialize/serialize class.
Here is the array:

> {"LaunchIDs":["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"],"FavoriteID":null,"Username":"Test","error":0,"message":"You have successfully logged in"}

The code for the array is

```
Public Class JSONCode
   Public LaunchIDs As Integer
   Public FavoriteIDAs Integer
   Public username As String
   Public [error] As Integer
   Public message As Integer
End Class
```

Here is how I'm using it inside the application.

```
 Dim client As New WebClient()
 Dim jsonResponse As String = "{""LaunchIDs"":[""2"",""3"",""4"",""5"",""6"",""7"",""8"",""9"",""10""],""FavoriteID"":null,""username"":""Test"",""error"":0,""message"":""You have successfully logged in""}")
 Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
 Dim response As JSONCode = serializer.Deserialize(Of JSONCode)(jsonResponse)
        code = response.error
        If code = 0 & response.message = "You have successfully logged in" Then
            LoginFunction = True
            botids = response.botids
            ListBox1.AddItem(botids)
        Else
            Alert(Style.Critical, response.message)
        End If
 End If
```

The array is going to be retrieved from a web address (After I fix this issue), so its kinda messy right now. Alert() is just a little custom msgBox function.

I get this error when I try and debug.
Type 'System.Int32' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration of class is wrong it should be

```
Public Class JSONCode_cor
    Public LaunchIDs As Integer()
    Public FavoriteID As Integer()
    Public username As String
    Public [error] As Integer
    Public message As String
End Class
```

This I use in code:

```
Dim jsonResponse As String = "{""LaunchIDs"":[""2"",""3"",""4"",""5"",""6"",""7"",""8"",""9"",""10""],""FavoriteID"":null,""username"":""Test"",""error"":0,""message"":""You have successfully logged in""}"
Dim serializer As New Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim response As Object = serializer.Deserialize(Of JSONCode_cor)(jsonResponse)
```

And it works. Your problem is that you declare LaunchIDs as `Integer` but in reality it is an array `Integer()`

Comment: frmMain.FlatListBox2.AddItem(LaunchIDs) That gave a value of "int32" or something, so I tried switching AddItem with AddRange. Now I get 
Error 1 Value of type '1-dimensional array of Integer' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Object' because 'Integer' is not a reference type.

Comment: That's the code I'm already using. Well I figured out the problem, had to make a function in order to convert the Integer to a String array.